# git merge status reports 'both modified` on file that appears at new path only in incoming

Tags: git

I am merging branch refactored into branch develop. The former, as the name implies, is a branch that refactors the folders, files, and namespaces of the project. With develop checked out, I run git merge refactored. Some conflicts are reported as expected. Amongst them, consider file Core.cs that in `develop` existed at path `Shared/src/Core/Core.cs`. In `refactored` this file has been moved into location `Common/Core/Core.cs`. However, git does not detect the move. Instead it reports the following.

Running `git status | select-string "/Core.cs" -SimpleMatch` I get all lines in the git status output that contain the file name. Interestingly I see:

> deleted: /Shared/src/Core/Core.cs
> both modified: /Common/Core/Core.cs

Further. `git ls-files -s /Common/Core/Core.cs` shows this file in all merge stages, which is bizzare because this path did not exist at all in develop:

```
> 
> 100644 be51adb6d3...b421a 1       Common/Core/Core.cs
> 100644 0736c00294...252e7 2       Common/Core/Core.cs
> 100644 1be6053172...3ca54 3       Common/Core/Core.cs
>
```

Can someone help me decipher this information?

I expected to see 1. But 2. is odd. I would expect to see something like new file added because `/Common/Core/Core.cs` only exists in `refactored`. I do not understand why the status is `both modified` and I do not understand why the file at `Common/Core/Core.cs` appears in stages 1, 2, and 3, for the same reasons.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects Take a look at `Tree Objects`

Comment: Look like works were done on develop after creating the refactored branch. Changes were made on the Core.cs on both sides (It cognitzed as move+edit). Analyse the conflict and make the necessary fixes to resolve it.

Comment: @Hugo Is a file showing as 'deleted' in one branch and 'both modified' in another the way a move can be reliably detected as per the `git status` output (of course, assuming changes in both branches)?

Comment: If there's only a file move, it should indicate "move". If there's a move and edit, it will show the delete and edit actions. I see your point regarding the conflict. a bit weird...